# How do I amend the text in a Qt Label?

Tags: qt, label, qlabel

I was wondering how to amend (or more specifically, add) text to a Qt Label, rather than just setting it using setText?

Comment: Just read the text, modify it and set it back.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing it... but that'll do if needs be.